# Need help trying to convert api built in code bootcamp for personal use

Tags: asp.net

admittedly stopped trying and forgot how to work this after 8 months of no work after the bootcamp but i just found some work and i need help getting the api we built in the bootcamp to run off my own personal database, the error i think im getting at this moment , because im sure there will be more after, is this :An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__1(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)

ive found the spot in the code i think responsible for this error but i cannot change any values and wouldnt know what to change it to: public class SpaOptions
{
private PathString _defaultPage = "/index.html";

```
    private string _packageManagerCommand = "npm";

    public PathString DefaultPage
    {
        get
        {
            return _defaultPage;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Value))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The value for DefaultPage cannot be null or empty.");
            }

            _defaultPage = value;
        }
    }
```

any advice would be great, i guess mentioning im pulling this error from my chrome browser window, not the console

Comment: so ive gotten past that and getting this error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)'


pretty sure im just messing up my connection string now if anyone can halp

Comment: figured it out woot